# Why redirect function change my url in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

When **def login()** function call and **redirect** to **def index(**) function my url change in the browser and look like *http://127.0.0.1:8000/error500index* this url. But logically url look like http://127.0.0.1:8000/index this. But error500 show in the url when i use redirect function, error500 is my last url in the **Project urls.py** and **APP urls.py**.

***Anyone help me out what is the happening?***

**view.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import WebUser

def index(request):
return render(request, 'index.html')

def login(request):
if (request.method == 'POST'):
    login_email = request.POST['email']
    login_password = request.POST['password']

    # Compare with Database where input email exist!
    try:
        CheckUser = WebUser.objects.get(email=login_email)
    except:
        return HttpResponse("User Dosen't Exist!")

    if (login_email == CheckUser.email and login_password == CheckUser.Password):
        
       #When redirect function call my url change and pick the last url from project urls.py and this url appears in the browser http://127.0.0.1:8000/error500index
        return redirect(index)
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Email or Password are wrong!")

else:
    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

**Project Urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('SIS_APP.urls')),
    path('index', include('SIS_APP.urls')),
    path('login', include('SIS_APP.urls')),
    path('register', include('SIS_APP.urls')),
    path('settings', include('SIS_APP.urls')),
    path('weather', include('SIS_APP.urls')),
    path('error404', include('SIS_APP.urls')),
    path('error500', include('SIS_APP.urls')),
]
```

**APP urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('index', views.index, name='index'),
    path('login', views.login, name='login'),
    path('register', views.register, name='register'),
    path('settings', views.settings, name='settings'),
    path('weather', weatherAPI.weather, name='weather'),
    path('error404', views.error404, name='error404'),
    path('error500', views.error500, name='error500'),
]
```

Comment: Hello @Mujahid if you want to use redirect to specific app url you have to use like this ```redirect('your_app_name:your_url_name')``` where url_name is name of your url example ```name='index'```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the slashes "/" in your urls. URLs are concatenated, so if you have, i.e,

```
path('index', views.index, name='index'), ## this will give ..indexsome-sub-route
path('index/', views.index, name='index'), ## this will give ..index/some-sub-route
```

Comment: Thank you Nihad. Now is working perfectly. :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not defining your URLs correctly. From the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect).

You will see that redirect can be used with a hardcoded link that is:

```
redirect("/index/")
```

And since you didn't add the slash in the URL we have:

```
redirect("index")
```

So it will pass the the value index to your URL. To fix it, add `/` to your URL definition.